# How to update or overwrite existing sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have 99% of this done. What it is already doing is combining 6-7 CSV files from two folders and putting them all into one Google Sheet Workbook. However, these files are update daily so as you can imagine I need to update/overwrite the Google Sheet Workbook also. Just can't figure out how to implement it into my already working code. Appreciate the help in advance.

Do I update, delete sheet, etc? I will of course add a timing trigger at the end of it to work correctly.

> **Error:** 10:13:16 AM    Error
> Exception: A sheet with the name "Employee Basic Summary with Supv.csv" already exists. Please enter another name.
> loadCSVFilesIntoSheets  @ googlesheets.gs:10

ERROR IMAGE
[image]

**CODE:**

```
function loadCSVFilesIntoSheets() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('CURRENTLY USING THIS FOR GOOGLE WORKBOOK 'ID' AND WORKING');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1ST CSV FOLDER 'ID' WORKING FINE');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('2ND CSV FOLDER 'ID' WORKING FINE');
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var vA=Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(file.getName());
    sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadCSVFilesIntoSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const ids = ["id1", "id2"];
  ids.forEach(id => {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      let shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
      var vA = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      let idx = shts.indexOf(file.getName());
      let sh;
      if (!~idx) {
        sh = ss.insertSheet(file.getName());
      } else {
        sh = ss.getSheetByName(shts[idx]);
        sh.clearContents();//Since this add's a legend to each entry with sheet name, and new Date() you could put a routine to remove some sections based upon date somewhere around here
      }
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([["Sheet Name:", sh.getName(),new Date()]]);
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var name = file.getName();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name) || ss.insertSheet(name);
```

Comment: If its existing you might want to add a `sh.clear();`

Comment: Well it would need to be  var name = DriveApp.getFilesByName;

Comment: @TheWizEd clear won't work if you look at the rest of the script. That would just clear the sheet not remove all the sheets. For  example the sheet would be empty, but sheet name is still the same aka the issue. The deletesheet function for all of them might work, but I worry you'd run into setting a separate script for that with a timed trigger.

Comment: @TheFlash, I think you are wrong on both counts.  `file` is a file so `file.getName()` is legit.  Second once `sh` is defined, if it exists `sh.clear()` is also legit.  That way if there was more data in the sheet than the new data set the old rows would be deleted and only the new data would be inserted in the sheet.  I leave it to the OP how to implement these things.

Comment: I think update might be the most accurate way to do it

Comment: @TheWizEd ... it's on a shared drive why would you not use 'driveapp.filegetname' vs 'file.getname'? Also to me the error has to do with the sheet name has nothing to do with  the interior data. I delete rows to test that theory prior to posting.

Comment: Also getname in general is undefined

Comment: @thewized -- I think it's a combo.. what about IF statement + update? or something? For example ... if exists then update etc